# convert sql query to sequelize query

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, feathersjs

how to convert this to sequelize query . I've tried using between but it does not have the same result. I dont think between is the solution , how about lte and gte ? Thank you

## using between

```
where: {
  createdAt: {
    [Op.between]: ["2018-07-08T14:06:48.000Z", "2019-10-08T22:33:54.000Z"]
  }
}
```

## convert this sql to sequelize query

```
SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE createdAt >= '2020-06-15 00:00:00' AND createdAt <= '2020-06-18 00:00:00'
```

Comment: `BETWEEN` is inclusive and equivalent to `value >= low and value <= high`  so it should yield the same results. Your issue may be with the actual data and possibly timezone

Answer (score 0):

You can include the same property more than once within the `where` and this would work like `AND` in your SQL query:

```
where: {
    createdAt: { [Op.gte]: '2020-06-15' },
    createdAt: { [Op.lte]: '2020-06-18' }
}
```